# grub.conf issue while OVA deployment to AWS ec2

Tags: linux, centos, grub, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to deploy an OVA to AWS. And came across a strange problem. AWS looks for file with name 'grub.conf' in all partitions and doesn't deploy OVA if multiple files exist with name 'grub.conf' in any location. It shows something like this:

```
{
        "Status": "deleted", 
        "SnapshotDetails": [
            {
                "UserBucket": {
                    "S3Bucket": "bucket", 
                    "S3Key": "dir/aws.ova"
                }, 
                "DiskImageSize": 29947222016.0, 
                "Format": "VMDK"
            }
        ], 
        "Description": "grub test1", 
        "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Multiple different grub/menu.lst files found [\"/usr/local/cold-inject-mounts/vol-xxxxxx/-dev-xvdf1/grub/grub.conf\", \"/boot/grub/grub.conf\", \"/usr/local/cold-inject-mounts/vol-xxxxx/-dev-xvdf2/boot/grub/grub.conf\"]", 
        "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-xxxxxxx"
}
```

This image had centos 5 in it. There is only one disk with three partition in it (sda1/2/3). I am wondering why doesn't it look into the default grub location instead scanning whole disk for file named 'grub.conf'?

Any inputs or work around for this?

Thanks in advance.